# KNPMenu + Matcher + Voter

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle

Evening to all,

I'm developing a breadcrumbs system by a KNP Menu ready coded. I'm getting a problem when trying to get breadcrumbs with theis own URI and name for a tree.

E.g: For /menuItem1/category1/ I am looking for [Menuitem](http://#) --> [Category1](http://#)

To match current URI with Child URI, I'm using this structure:

```
$matcher = new Matcher();
$voter = new UriVoter($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$matcher->addVoter($voter);

$treeIterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new \Knp\Menu\Iterator\RecursiveItemIterator(
            new \ArrayIterator(array($trail))
        ),
        \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    );

$breadcrumbs = new \Knp\Menu\Iterator\CurrentItemFilterIterator($treeIterator, $matcher);
```

The problem is that I get the complete trail for the breadcrumbs butnot their own links. Any sugestions? Not much time. I'll explain better if someone need it.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Now I can retrieve current menu item but what I want is to get Current Menu Item and their parents (names and links).